# PVmove copies the data or move the data?

Tags: lvm, pvmove

I executed a pvmove command between 2 volumes but now I can see the data in both storages. So does pvmove copy or move the data ??

command executed in servers

`pvmove /dm/dm-1 /dm/dm-0`

Answer (score 5):

pvmove will copy ( backup ) the data into the mirror with temp mirrorlv  in order to resume the activity if its interrupted in the mid and  move the data from one disk to new disk, once pvmove done   " lvdisplay -m lvpath" will diplay the maps of the LE on a new disk

pvmove -v currentdisk newdisk  will show the complete procedure what it is doing while execution .

Answer (score 2):

pvmove copies the data, and also changes the LV to use the new location instead of the old one.

Note that the old physical volume (PV) is still attached to the VG, so if the PV is now unused by any LV's, you might want to remove the PV from the VG.

Comment: And, afterwards, you still need to remove the appropriate volume groups from the appropriate physical volumes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your command is right, but pvmove itself literally moves the extents from one device to another.